# Laravel - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code in my controller:

```
    public function contact(){

        $people = ['Michael', 'martin', 'Peter', 'Marian'];

        return view('contact', compact('people'));
    }
```

and in my contact.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>Contact Page</h1>

    @if (count($people))

        <ul>

        @foreach(@people as $person)
            
            <li>{{$person}}</li>

        @endforeach

        </ul>

    @endif

@endsection

@section('footer')



@endsection
```

I am getting the error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/mao/Documents/blog/resources/views/contact.blade.php)

I do not see the error.. been rewriting it twice. this should be correct as far as i can see on online guides?

Comment: change @people tp $people in foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a mistype in your `foreach`

Try this

```
@foreach($people as $person)
    <li>{{$person}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Change the `@` in `$`

Comment: Jesus... i actually done this typo twice in a row then.. i rewrite it once.. thank you so much, what a stupid mistake

Comment: Haha! Atleast now you can be more sensitive in your code brother.

Answer (score 0):

**change @people to $people  (@ => $)**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>Contact Page</h1>

    @if (count($people))

        <ul>

        @foreach($people as $person)
            
            <li>{{$person}}</li>

        @endforeach

        </ul>

    @endif

@endsection

@section('footer')



@endsection
```